# swf action script convert into flv

Tags: php, ffmpeg

this is a action script : symmetrydigital-labs.com/junior/kazim/portal/flv/Shahid_Kapoor_07.swf

image is call outside from server.
i want to convert this .swf file into .flv and generate thumbnail.

Problem :
1: .swf file converts only video not with image (call from outsource) .swf
2: code was not run in server run only in localhost.

and i am try to using this command

```
$ffmpeg = 'C:\FFmpeg\ffmpeg-20130614-git-6fe419b-win32-static\bin\ffmpeg';    
$ffmpeg = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';   
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i Shahid_Kapoor_07.swf Shahid_Kapoor_07.flv";   
$image = "$ffmpeg -i Shahid_Kapoor_07.swf -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y  abc.jpg";
shell_exec($cmd);
shell_exec($image);
```

Comment: The complete ffmpeg console outputs for each command are required.

Comment: need more clarification ?